# Mysql will not restart

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to start the mysql server using the command

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

but it won't start. I don't get a specific error all I see is

`* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                              [fail]`

i've tried the same command but using `restart` instead but same results. I've also tried to start it using

`sudo service start mysql`

I am stuck at this point. please let me know if I can provide anymore information.

Thank you.

Here is my mysql error.log

```
150505 21:43:49 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150505 21:43:49 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150505 21:43:49 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150505 21:43:49 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150505 21:43:49 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150505 21:43:49 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150505 21:43:49 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150505 21:43:49 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150505 21:43:49 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 30152041
150505 21:43:49  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 30161741
```

Comment: did u try it after restarting your system. Sometimes it works.

Comment: @RushikeshDaad yes I tried restarting my computer but doesn't do anything.

Comment: and what does your mysql error log say?

Comment: @pala_ I've added a snippet from the log.

Comment: you may be running two version or the mysql port you have used may be busy check for it

Comment: @GuranjanSingh there's nothing about that log entry that indicates a failure, other than complaining it wasn't shut down properly. is that right up to the end of your log? is mysql running? `ps aux | grep mysql` ?

Answer (score 8):

I know this question was posted long back. But I have figured out a solution since I had the same problem. This error might occurs due to multiple installations of MySQL, in the operating system.

```
sudo ps -A|grep mysql
```

Kill the process of `mysql`

```
sudo pkill mysql
```

Then run the command

```
sudo ps -A|grep mysqld
```

kill process of `mysqld`

```
sudo pkill mysqld
```

Now you can safely restart MySQL server

```
sudo service mysql restart    
mysql -u root -p
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, you just saved an evening for 2 devs.

Comment: Happy to hear that @VolodymyrI.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` this should work.

Or else

restart server using `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Still down.

run `service mysql status` and check script name(this will be sometimes **mysqld**).
then

```
service mysqld status
service mysqld stop
service mysqld start
```

Comment: How is this different from anything that I have already tried?